# Combine jQuery UI progress bar / sllider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar, jquery-ui-slider

I want to use Jquery UI slider as media player seek bar. I want to show both buffering and seek bar. Is there any way that I can do both these with a single Slider/ Progress bar

Currently I am using separate slider for both

// For Seek Bar

```
jwplayer(player_id).onTime(function(a){
  $("#slider-range" ).slider({ 
          max: a.duration,
          value:a.position,
   })
});
```

// For Buffering

```
jwplayer(player_id).onBufferChange(function(a){
    $("#slider-buffer" ).slider({
         value:a.bufferPercent,
        })
```